# How can I sort this php directory list by name?

Tags: php, sorting, directory

So, simply want my webdrive folder to be "browseable", so I found this script that does it for me.
The problem is, that the list is not sorted by name
How needs the code to be modified so its sorted by filename?

```
<?php
$dir_open = opendir('.');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
        $link = "<a href='./$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
        echo $link;
    }
}

closedir($dir_open);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the filenames in an array, then sort them using [`sort()`](https://www.php.net/sort)

```
$files = [];
$dir_open = opendir('.');
while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
        $files[] = $filename; // store filename
    }
}
closedir($dir_open);

// Then, sort and display
sort($files);

foreach ($files as $filename) {
    $link = "<a href='./$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
    echo $link;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I wanted to sort differently (e.g, by date), how would I do it?

Comment: You could also store in the array, the `filemtime()` information. And sort using `usort()`.

Comment: Or `$files[$filename] = filemtime($filename);` then `asort($files)`. There are many ways, but not easy to describe in comments ;)